# Installing openCV on raspberry pi for video detection error avformat.h not found

Tags: raspbian, video, opencv, c++, ffmpeg

I want to install opencv on the raspberry pi for image detection on a video I have followed [this tutorial](http://robertcastle.com/2014/02/installing-opencv-on-a-raspberry-pi/) but the videos are not to be played or proccessd. I tried to install it again to make sure ffmpeg is enabled error appears during config.

```
ffmpeg/avformat.h is not found
```

I have searched and what I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444926/videocapture-is-not-working-in-opencv-2-4-2) the answer is to make sure that ffmpeg is installed on the pi before making the opencv so I installed the ffmpeg went through all the steps till make and sudo make install in the main directory of the pi but still when I

```
ccmake ../ then press c
```

to config same error appears I have tried to put the ffmpeg file inside the release file and put the avformat.h just in opencv/release/ffmpeg same error file not found how can I solve this problem.

Comment: did you install ffmpeg from a repository like apt-get install ffmpeg or build it from source? It looks like you are missing the development files try apt-cache search ffmpeg and see if there is a developer package. might jsut be ffmpeg-dev, but I can not check right now.

Comment: no I did build it from the source file

Comment: Have you solved this problem, yet? I am working on the exact same problem here. I tried several methods that might be helpful for you. When I installed ffmpeg using 'apt-get', opencv is able to find the 'avformat.h' file with no problem. I searched and found that 'avformat.h' is in directory '/usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h'. Then I tried to install ffmpeg from source code compiling, and the error shows like you described. I searched and found that the file is in directory '/usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h' So the difference here is 'local', so I think that's the reason why opencv

Comment: Me too :) Havent't looked long, but all pages/posts are same thing. Not found...